# How to get json object of google maps places api in android?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

Is there any way to get the json data from google maps places api in android. I am using the following link to retrieve data.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Store+in+Lahore&type=clothing_store&key=----
```

it returns data in json format. Please help me how can I get the data form the above in android.

Comment: add an example of the data returned so you can be helped out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old question. But I hope it will be useful for others in future.

First, you have to add this to your module level `build.gradle`,

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Next step is to create an AsyncTask,

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private JSONObject jsonObject;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        System.out.println(jsonObject); //use jsonObject here
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {
            Looper.prepare();
            String latitude = args[0];
            String longitude = args[1];
            String radius = args[2];
            String name = args[3];
            String key = "YOUR_API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER";

            String uri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" 
                    + "location=" + latitude + "," + longitude 
                    + "&radius=" + radius 
                    + "&name=" + name
                    + "&key="+ key; // you can add more options here

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(new ArrayList<NameValuePair>()));
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpPost).getEntity();

            InputStream stream = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }

            stream.close();
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(sBuilder.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then execute the AsyncTask from wherever you want. (Maybe from MainActivity),

```
String latitude = String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
String longitude = String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);
String radius = "2000"; // 2 Kilometer
String name = "hospital";

MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
myAsyncTask.execute(latitude, longitude, radius, name);
```

You can add more option while fetching places from Google Places, for example *keyword*, *language* etc. Read more about those options and how to use them [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

Comment: Thanks alot. It'ill be helpful for others :)

Comment: Nice. it's not related, but you said "Maybe from MainActivity", how to do that exactly? I've tried to `.excute()`, but I don't know how to get the return value of `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)  can help you about that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and  [JSON Parser Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm) for JSON data retrieval.